# Visual Studio MVC 5 and SQL Server Express inquiry

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am attempting a simple MVC 5 web application. I had it on LocalDB and it was find. Now I want to use SQL Server Express.
Just would like to ask:

Does the sequence has to be: 1, Designing your models, 2, Connecting to SQL Server from my Visual Studio 2013 3, SQL Server sees no database there and will creates one?

Is it correct or it works just for the LocalDB?

Or can I do it the reverse way? 1, Creating database and tables in SQL Server, 2, Visual Studio 2013 automatically generates models for me?

I'm new to this. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research. I already found out Code First and Database First.